# In MongoDB, why does updating/finding exact documents fail when the document has an embedded document?

Tags: mongodb

I'm using pymongo for reference.

So if I have a document like this:

```
{
    'name': 'bill',
    'color': 'blue',
    'subdocument': {
        'title': 'Untitled',
        'content': 'Hello World',
    }
}
```

If I find this document doing db.users.find()[0] and then pass it as an argument to update, Mongo will not find the document to update unless I remove the subdocument.  Passing the found document to find_one also fails unless the subdocument is removed.

I need to specify all the fields for the sake of optimized locking.  How can I easily retrieve the document, update it, and pass the original fields as requirements for not having been changed?

Comment: Dan, can you post full code for both Python and the shell so I can help debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I primarily was interested in this for the purpose of optimistic locking, I have found a better solution than my original attempt, thanks to Scott from the [MongoDB Users Group](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/3f9663547f57e1f9)

The solution is to use a "version" counter field, and only update if the field has not been changed.  Upon each update of the document, the query doing the updating should increment the counter.  [This is faster](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/MongoNewsletterArticleDec2010zT2XeCE-PGrgf5fgGdBAxgOx2qw), since all of the fields don't have to be scanned and compared for the change to be made.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are encountering a [deep bug in MongoDB](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2592). You can see a similar issue [in this bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5030).

Embedded documents are compared as binary rather than compared as documents. So `subdocument: {a:1,b:2}` is different from `subdocument:{b:2,a:1}` even though they should not be.

See [this comment](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2592?focusedCommentId=24285&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-24285) for why this may be a problem.

Of course, that first bug is both serious and well over a year old, so it's questionable that this will be fixed any time soon. In fact, it's currently unscheduled.

Comment: Well, it's interesting, because even if the subdocument is empty (i.e. just {}) the modification still wont work.  Does this bug happen even when ordering isn't an issue, as in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Did you put a '$set' term in?

Here's what I did:

```
d = {
    'name': 'bill',
    'color': 'blue',
    'subdocument': {
        'title': 'Untitled',
        'content': 'Hello World',
    }
}

db.name.insert(d)
f = db.name.find_one({'name':'bill'})
print f
{u'color': u'blue', u'_id': ObjectId('4f8dbc834647df1428000002'), u'name': u'bill', u'subdocument': {u'content': u'Hello World', u'title': u'Untitled'}}

db.name.update(f, {'$set':{'name':'fred'}})

f = db.name.find_one({'name':'fred'})
print f
{u'color': u'blue', u'_id': ObjectId('4f8dbc834647df1428000002'), u'name': u'fred', u'subdocument': {u'content': u'Hello World', u'title': u'Untitled'}}
```

Comment: It doesn't work even using $set.  The problem is with the first argument passed to update.  If it contains any embedded documents, Mongo won't find the document to update.

Comment: Are you using the result of the find as I do above? It worked for me using your sample document.